# Wine-Water Paradox, how to derive $\dfrac{3x_t-1}{8}$

Tags: probability

> A mixture is known to contain a mix of wine and water in proportions such that the amount of wine divided by the amount of water is a ratio $x$ lying in the interval $1 / 3 \leq x \leq 3$ (i.e. $25-75 \%$ wine). We seek the probability, $P^{*}$ say, that $x \leq 2$. (i.e. less than or equal to $66 \%$.)

> We do not know $x$, the wine to water ratio. We only know that it lies in an interval between the minimum of one quarter wine over three quarters water on one end (i.e. $25 \%$ wine), to the maximum of three quarters wine over one quarter water on the other (i.e. $75 \%$ wine).

> Now, making use of the principle of indifference, we may assume that $x$ is uniformly distributed. Then the chance of finding the ration $x$ any fixed threshold $x_{t}$, with $x_{\min }<x_{t}<x_{\max }$, should linearly depend on the value $x_{t}$. So the probability value is the number
> $$
> \operatorname{Prob}\left\{x \leq x_{t}\right\}=\frac{x_{t}-x_{\min }}{x_{\max }-x_{\min }}=\frac{1}{8}\left(3 x_{t}-1\right)
> $$
> As a function of the threshold value $x_{t}$, this is the linearly growing function that is 0 resp. 1 at the end points $x_{\text {min }}=\frac{1 / 4}{3 / 4}=\frac{1}{3}$ resp. $x_{\text {max }}=\frac{3 / 4}{1 / 4}=3$.

I have no idea where $\dfrac{3x_t-1}{8}$ comes from.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine/water_paradox

Comment: Isn't it just $\frac{x_t-\frac{1}{3}}{3-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{3x_t-1}{9-1}=\frac{3x_t-1}{8}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
{x_t-x_{\text{min}}\over
x_{\text{min}}-x_{\text{min}}}
={x_t-1/3\over 3 - 1/3}
={3x_t-1\over9-1}=\frac18(3x_t-1)
$$